# Search the webpage source for urls?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way to search a webpage's source for all strings in a url format and put them into an array. Something I could execute on any page using Firebug's console or something similar. I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Everything I try just returns NULL. Thanks.

Comment: u mean all the urls in a page?

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
document.body.innerHTML.match(/https?:\/\/[^'">\s]+/g);
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I need! Is there a way I can get everything within the <html> and not limit myself to the <body>? Thanks!

Comment: @Ber53rker For the entire contents of `<html>` try `document.documentElement` instead of `document.body`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var anchor_tags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

var urls = [];
for(var i=0;i<anchor_tags.length;i++){
 urls.push(anchor_tags[i].href); 
}
console.log(ursl);
```

Comment: every url is not inside anchor tags . in ex:- <form action="http/example.com/index">   ;)

Answer (score 0):

For all urls within html:

```
(function(){
    var allURLs = document.head.innerHTML.match(/https?:\/\/[^'">\s]+/g).join() 
                + document.body.innerHTML.match(/https?:\/\/[^'">\s]+/g).join();
    console.log(allURLs);
})()
```